# How to animate and align interaction between a character and a stationary, articulating object?

Tags: unity, animation, blender

Let's say I have an cannon and a person in Blender (I haven't made it yet), and I wanted to make an animation where the soldier loads a round into the cannon; and then export it into Unity. [Here's a video of the reload I want to achieve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfYF_AAtIG4&t=11m23s).

How would I go about making the animation? Should I:

1. Animate the soldier reloading the cannon animation all in Blender, then export the soldier and cannon into Unity as one combined model.
2. Export the cannon and soldier model separately, then use the Unity animator to make each animation for the cannon and soldier (although I don't know how you would line up the animation of the soldier with the cannon).
3. Export the cannon and soldier model separately, but then put the 2 models under an empty game object in Unity, then animate the game object so that there's just one animation clip.
4. Some other workflow that people use.

I really want to know the workflow of creating animations for objects that interact with other objects. If you're able to link any helpful videos or articles, it would be a great help to me!

Comment: You should look into Inverse Kinematics since that's a common way of animating characters to interact with other objects in the scene. The basic idea is that you create target points for body parts (like a hand) and the IK system will figure out the best way to manipulate the joints to put that body part where you want it to go.

Comment: Are there any helpful videos that could help me that you know?

Comment: I don't have any specific recommendations; I'm sure you can do a web search and find some good results.